# Condition to skip data is not working as intended

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi everyone I copied this from a previous post and matched it up to my needs. I'm having trouble preventing it from sending the entire list when the word Sent is in column 10. I've messed with the coding more than I would like to at this point and feel it's getting messy.

Can someone take a look at it and see what is missing?

It will send the email and do everything I need, but so far it just sends all the lines of data regardless if `Sent` is in the column or not.

```
function sendEmails2() {

    //setup function
    var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var StartRow = 2;
    var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
    var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
    var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

    var message = "";
    //iterate loop
    for (i in AllValues) {

        //set current row
        var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

        //define column to check if sent
        var EmailSent = CurrentRow[10];

        //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
        if (EmailSent == "sent") 
         continue;

        //set HTML template for information
        message +=
        "<p><b>Sales Rep: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Case ID: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Signing Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Draft Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Sign to Draft: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Enrolled Debt: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p><br><br>";

        //set the row to look at
        var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

        //mark row as "sent"
        ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 10).setValue("sent");
   }

   //define who to send email to 
   var SendTo = "my email address" + "," + "";

   //set subject line
   var Subject = "NEW DEAL CLOSED";

   //send the actual email  
   MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Dfor+%28i+in+AllValues%29+%7B+++%2F%2Fset+current+row++var+CurrentRow+%3D+AllValues%5Bi%5D%3B

Comment: It looks to me - after properly indenting the code - that the `MailApp.sendEmail()` function is outside the loop and not subject to any condition, so will always send an email when  `sendEmails2()` is called.

Comment: any suggestions on where it should go? I moved } after the mailapp.send and it sends me like 100 emails with the entire spreadsheet contents.

Answer (score 0):

mistake is there in var EmailSent = CurrentRow[10] where the column being considered actually in 11. When taking the whole data range from sheet, the column index starts from 0 and so the actual index to be taken should be 9 for 10th column

```
 //define column to check if sent
    var EmailSent = CurrentRow[9];
```